# Disable swipe gesture in child component in Android Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, swipe, overlap, composable, exposeddropdownmenu

As mentioned by the title, I want to disable the swipe gestures `ExposedDropdownMenuBox` in a Composable.

The reason is sometimes, the swipe triggers both Drawer's swipe to open and the `ExposedDropdownMenuBox`. Specifically, when you swipe on the Dropdown menu title.

How can I swipe over the `ExposedDropdownMenuBox` to open the Drawer only, not trigger the dropdown menu?

Sample Activity of a Drawer & a DropDown Menu:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MyDrawerTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
                ) {
                    Body("Android")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Body(name: String) {
    Scaffold(
        drawerContent = {
            Text("Drawer title $name", modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp))
            Divider()
            // Drawer items
        }
    ) {
        // Screen content
        DropBox()
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
@Composable
fun DropBox(){
    val options = listOf("Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3", "Option 4", "Option 5")
    var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var selectedOptionText by remember { mutableStateOf(options[0]) }

    ExposedDropdownMenuBox(
        expanded = expanded,
        onExpandedChange = {
            expanded = !expanded
        }
    ) {
        TextField(
            readOnly = true,
            value = selectedOptionText,
            onValueChange = { },
            label = { Text("Label") },
            trailingIcon = {
                ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.TrailingIcon(
                    expanded = expanded
                )
            },
            colors = ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.textFieldColors()
        )
        ExposedDropdownMenu(
            expanded = expanded,
            onDismissRequest = {
                expanded = false
            }
        ) {
            options.forEach { selectionOption ->
                DropdownMenuItem(
                    onClick = {
                        selectedOptionText = selectionOption
                        expanded = false
                    }
                ) {
                    Text(text = selectionOption)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Swipe on the Title of the dropdown menu cause the Drawer open and dropdown menu open at the same time. As shown in the Screenshot**

[image: Overlap drawer and dropdown menu]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Compose [1.4.0-alpha04](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-animation#1.4.0-alpha04), the issue seems to be solved, i.e. the app does not open the burger menu while swiping upon the dropdown menu item.

Before, I had a workaround using menu offset to check if the burger menu is actually in the closed position:

```
if (scaffoldState.drawerState.offset.value == HomeScreenVM.closedMenuOffset) { //Perform task if the burger menu is closed}
```

And `closedMenuOffset` is a static var

```
 companion object {
     var closedMenuOffset = 0f
        set(value) {
            if (field > value) field = value
        }
 }
```